# Export emails from outlook while preserving folder structure

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, pst

I have to trim down our teams outlook files to meet the size reduction of the exchange server. We are moving to a new system that does not utilise .PST.

How can I extract/export all the emails we have in several PST files over the years to just .eml's in folder?

I also need to preserve existing folder structure in the PST.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what your first sentence has to do with your question. What are you trying to do? You need to migrate your Outlook e-mails in PST files another system? How many e-mails in total, how many users, and how many folders do you need to preserve structure for? What e-mail system will you be using and what is e-mail client you intend to use to interact with that email system? Initial thought is to use ThunderBird with several add-ons to 1) connect to Exchange Server (exQuilla) and ImportExportTools to save your e-mails as .eml to a folder.

Comment: Where do you want to export your emails from? If from PSTs, you have them already.

Comment: The IT department says we will no longer have access to the PST files (for some ungodly reason) So essentially, I need to extract all the .eml/.msg from the PST files I currently have.

Comment: @JonYork, I can recommend the commercial tool of my company that does the trick. It can export emails/items from PST files into EML or MSG files while preserving folder structure and even folder types (for importing them later if needed).

Comment: what tool is that?